# SQLite in Android: when I pass any name that contains a quote, it throws and error

Tags: android, sqlite

Adapter.java

```
public String getID(String i) throws SQLException
    {
        db=DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String ij="No Track Found";
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID}, KEY_NAME + "=" + "'"+i+"'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
                if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
                if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    ij=mCursor.getString(0);

                }
                return ij ;
    }
```

The Question is when I pass any song's name that contain "'"(e.g. alexander's blade) , it throws and error. Otherwise all fine.

Comment: You have to escape those characters.

Comment: Simply double your **'** s

Comment: But how to escape@JonasCz

Comment: I answered **how**. Read my comment.

Comment: Thanks all for letting me know the use of Escape character. \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your method like this:

```
Cursor c = bd.query(Constantes.TABELA_APLICATIVO, COLS, "urlandroid = ?", new String[]{url}, null, null, null);
```

The caracter "?" represents the values on Third parameter(String[]).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the selectionArgs parameter:

```
db.query(true,                  //distinct
         TABLE,                 //table
         new String[] {KEY_ID}, //columns
         KEY_NAME + "=?",       //selection
         new String[] {i},      //selectionArgs
         null,                  //groupBy
         null,                  //having
         null,                  //orderBy
         null                   //limit
         );
```

Using selectionArgs also help to prevent SQL Injection